# Dismissing Android's system dialogue which was triggered by my app

Tags: android, bluetooth

The scenario is as follows:

First, my app executes [the example code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability) for requesting user's approval to make the device Bluetooth-discoverable. This request opens up some kind of a system dialog, which asks the user "An app wants to make your phone visible to other Bluetooth devices for X seconds" and the user has to either accept or reject the request.

While that dialog is still showing (meaning that the user didn't interact with it yet), and in the meantime something else has happened in my app, then I want to be able to dismiss the dialog or cancel that request, on behalf of the user. Like "forget it, that's not relevant any more".

Is that possible in any way?